# What is the Greek name for Joshua?

Tags: word-study

Help me, please and thank you. A Sunday School lesson needs this answer as soon as possible. I'm not able to find it by myself.

Comment: Hello - Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  When you have a minute, please take the tour (below)

Comment: I've voted to close this question, as is it is a 'do my homework' question; and also not to do with the meaning of the Bible or Biblical texts, or at least specifies none.

Answer (score 2):

In Hebrews 4:8 the writer refers to Joshua historically and calls him ιησους in the Greek language. This reads as 'Jesus' in English and is, of course, the same name as Jesus Christ the Son of God.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word for Joshua is Jesus (in English) or Iesous (transliterated from the Greek).  The Hebrew word Joshua (and Jesus/Iesous) all mean "Yahweh (= Jehovah) is salvation" or "Jehovah is deliverance", etc.  An alternate spelling in the Hebrew is Hoshea.

Comment: Yarweh? With -r-?

Answer (score 0):

It can also refer to Jesus:-

> Strong's Concordance
>   **Iésous: Jesus or Joshua, the name of the Messiah, also three other Isr.**
>   Original Word: Ἰησοῦς, οῦ, ὁ
>   Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine
>   Transliteration: Iésous
>   Phonetic Spelling: (ee-ay-sooce')
>   Definition: Jesus or Joshua, the name of the Messiah, also three other Isr
>   Usage: Jesus; the Greek form of Joshua; Jesus, son of Eliezer; Jesus, surnamed Justus.
>
> Strong's Concordance
>   Yehoshua: "the LORD is salvation," Moses' successor, also the name of a number of Isr.
>   Original Word: יְהוֹשׁוּעַ
>   Part of Speech: proper name, masculine; proper name, of a location; proper name
>   Transliteration: Yehoshua
>   Phonetic Spelling: (yeh-ho-shoo'-ah)
>   Definition: "the LORD is salvation", Moses' successor, also the name of a number of Isr

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late to help the class, but there are 3 main spellings of the name in the  Greek text:
IESU, IESUS, IESON and if memory serves me right IESOU some times

Comment: These are different case forms of the same name, not different "spellings".

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Actually, all are wrong, apart from IESOU.

Comment: Yes, you are right fdb, Omicron Upsilon, whats the difference in English any way! That's the problem with using a smart phone with no LXX app to cut an paste from:)
Below are the accual spellings of Iesoi son of Naun's name:
Jos 1:1   Ἰησοῖ (IESOI ) 
Jos_1:10  Ἰησοῦς (IESOUS / Jesus)
Jos_2:23  Ἰησοῦν (ISOUN )